Why nitration of aniline carried out after acetylation give ortho and para major products?
I was reading about the meta directing nature of anilinium cations and the answer mentioned that these reactions are usually carried out with 90-98% sulphuric acid. At these concentrations I would expect that even the protected acetanilides would get protonated and should give para/meta major products like anilinium.
Why does that not happen? Why do they give o-p major products?

:/ You're mixing two two things. Direct "extreme" nitration and normal one, using protecting group.

@Mithoron Uh, I never read about "extreme" nitration before, could you explain a bit please? Also, shouldn't anilines be easier to nitrate anyways, because it's a more active ring both before and after protonation compared to acetanilide?

You just did - it's the one you mention from your link. You got your learning in somewhat wrong order ;)

@Mithoron Ok, so just to confirm, acetanilide being a worse base than aniline does not get protonated easily, thus remains activated and gets nitrated in mild conditions giving o-p products. While aniline gets protonated easily, becoming anilinium deactivating the ring and requring concentrated acid for nitration. Right? I think this makes sense.

Aniline is too good so it needs to be deactivated, either with acetyl, or via complete protonation. Normally you'd get something like "aniline black".
